# Jetty custom status message ??

Tags: rest, clojure, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am writing a service in clojure (using ring and compojure) which should change the status message. It is running on embedded Jetty 8. For example I have

```
200 OK
```

and I would like to have something like

```
200 <custome message>
```

In the EJB world there was possibility to set up header "X-Http-Status-Message" which does some magic behind the scene and changed message in response.

Is there any header in Jetty which allow me to do the same thing??
or Is there any other way in clojure to do it??

Answer (score 0):

Not with a magic header like that.

The status reason has to be set along with the status code in the same call in Jetty.
You can use either [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.setStatus(int, String)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Response.html#setStatus%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).

Example:

```java
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "Alrighty");
}
```

Note that some error conditions this status reason cannot be overridden.  But generally, use of [`HttpServletResponse.sendError(int, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ring documentation, you can only set the status code, not message:

https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/wiki/Concepts

Also, the `ring.util.servlet/set-status` function invokes [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse .setStatus(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int%29):

```
(defn set-status
  "Update a HttpServletResponse with a status code."
  [^HttpServletResponse response, status]
  (.setStatus response status))
```

Whole implementation is here: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj#L64

It should be fairly trivial to change Ring to add optional support for status message.

I suppose that the change could be introduced to the `ring.util.servlet/update-servlet-response` function:

```
(defn update-servlet-response
  "Update the HttpServletResponse using a response map."
  [^HttpServletResponse response, {:keys [status headers body]}]
  (when-not response
    (throw (Exception. "Null response given.")))
  (when status
    (set-status response status))
  (doto response
    (set-headers headers)
    (set-body body)))
```

For example by adding status-message key to the response map.

https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj#L105